# Glitch in texture paint?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting

I set up the texture paint but when I started to use different color this happened. Not on the all of object. Why is this happening ?

[image]

Comment: Those UVs are a mess... try seeing if the problem persists if you Smart UV Unwrap? If it fixed itself, that means it was probably a UV mapping issue, not a texture paint issue.

Comment: Your unwrap doesn't look very good, also you should try to increase the brush bleeding: in the T panel > Options tag > Project Paint > Bleed value

Answer (score 1):

You have to try to unwrap it correctly because if the UVs are stretched like that 
it isn't going to work. You can try the minimize stretch feature for that[image]